# Почему не два алерта, а три?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция:

```
  Array.prototype.myFunc=function(){ ...... }
```

И если использовать такую запись:

```
var array = ['a', 'b'];
for(var ev in array) {
alert(array[ev]);
}
```

То будет не 2 алерта, а 3, т.е. первый алерт будет 'a', второй 'b', а третий 'function(){ ...... }'  почему?  т.е. в третем алерте будет написана функция которая создана в виде

```
Array.prototype.myFunc=function(){ ...... }
```

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/prototype#метод-obj-hasownproperty
http://learn.javascript.ru/native-prototypes

Comment: повторю еще раз: расширять встроенные объекты  - зло: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qypPM/

Comment: >расширять встроенные объекты - зло

всё зависит от ситуации, например подобный метод достаточно удобен:

    Object.prototype.in = function(array){
         return !!~array.indexOf(this.valueOf())
    }

    if(someVariable.in(someCollection)) { ... }

это просто пример, т.к. далеко не всегда eval === evil или "расширять встроенные объекты - зло"

P.S. "Только ситхи всё возводят в абсолют"

Comment: я показал почему. к удобству это не имеет ни какого отношения. ну и по ссылке там говорят почем именно Object не расширять.

Comment: ваш пример к расширению объектов не имеет никакого отношения, он показыает неправильное использования eval

Comment: eval там ни причем , eval использован только для того, чтобы показать, что ссылок на переменную нет. (выполнить произвольный код в scope) можно и без eval, но будет не так наглядно. частично обойти можно, объявив функцию в родительской области видимости.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Потому что цикл `for .. in` итерирует по свойствам объекта.

Из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/For...in) (перевод мой):

> `for .. in` не следует использовать для итерации по массиву, если порядок индексов важен. Индексы массива -- всего лишь *перечислимые* свойства с именами, являющимися целыми числами, и более ничем не отличаются от обыкновенных свойств объекта. Нет никакой гарантии, что `for .. in` пробежит индексы в любом ожидаемом порядке; кроме того, он пробежит *все* перечислимые свойства, включая не являющиеся целыми числами, а также унаследованные.

Добавив `myFunc`, вы добавили свойство ко всем массивам.

Я бы посоветовал использовать просто

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    alert(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: for in лучше использовать только для циклов внутри {}, и чтобы он не проверял все свойства, в том числе и унаследованные можно использовать if(array[ev].hasOwnProperty(ev)) - тогда в цикле не будет унаследованных свойств

Comment: @makregistr: и вообще http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629004/276994